# Laravelの新規プロジェクトを作成したい

Tags: php, laravel

#### 実現したいこと

Laravelの新規プロジェクトを作成したい

実行環境・バージョン
xampp
PHP 8.2.4
Laravel Installer 5.0.4

#### 発生しているエラー

```
Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "your-token"
```

新規プロジェクトを作成するために入力したコマンド

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel sample_project_blog
```

#### 原因の仮説と今の現状

##### 現状

cssのbootstrapのファイルを削除しようとしたところLaravelを動かすのに必要なbootstrap/app.phpファイルを削除してしまいました。
また、Laravelプロジェクトフォルダごと一度削除して新規Laravelプロジェクトを作成しようと実行しておりました。

##### 仮説

githubのプライベートトークンが無効な文字列としてcomposer.jsonに書かれているからプライベートトークンをプログラムとして動くように有効なコードとして登録する必要があるのではないか

仮説を実行するためにcomposer.jsonファイルを探しましたが、プロジェクトを作成する際に上記のエラーが出た為、composer.jsonファイルが生成されていないのではないかと思いファイルが探せなかった為、解決方法が分からずこの度は質問をさせていただきました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自分が追記したファイルのパス
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\auth.json

githubのアクセストークンを追記したところLaravelの新規プロジェクトを作成することができました。